# Perl: insert elements of array in file by substitution

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, insert-update, perl-data-structures

1) I have a textfile. The file contains a STRING that needs to be substituted with multiple lines, those lines are elements of an array.

Contents of file:

```
line 1  
line 2   
line 3  
STRING  
line 4  
...
```

2.)I have an array

```
@array = qw (ele1 ele2 ele3);
```

This array can have 2 or more elements.

3.)I want to open the file, substitute the STRING with following pseudocode:

```
s/STRING/@array/;
```

and write results in a new file.

4.) The new file with result should look like this :

```
line 1  
line 2   
line 3  
ele1  
ele2  
ele3
line 4  
...
```

Here a piece of pseudocode:

```
open (FILE "< file.txt");
open (OUTPUT "> new.txt");
@array=qw(ele1 ele2 ele3);
for $line (<FILE>) {
    s/STRING/@array/;
    print OUTPUT "$line\n";
}
close FILE;
close OUTPUT;
```

Any suggestions on how to insert elements of an array into this file using substitution?

I am not looking for solutions based on `sed`, `awk`, `cat` or Unix shell tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
my $str = "line 1
line 2
line 3
STRING
line 4";
my @array = qw (ele1 ele2 ele3);
$str =~ s/STRING/join"\n",@array/e;
say $str;
```

**Output:**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
ele1
ele2
ele3
line 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without the `/e` operator, using the `$"` variable (`$LIST_SEPARATOR` if you use English), which changes how arrays are joined when interpolated into strings (including the right-hand side of a `s///`):

```perl
$" = "\n";
@array = qw(ele1 ele2 ele3);
open FILE, 'file.txt';
open OUTPUT, '>', 'new.txt';
while (<FILE>) {
  s/^STRING$/@array/;
  print OUTPUT;
}
```

Note also that you need `^` and `$` anchors on your regexp if you don't want it to match lines *containing* the word "STRING".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use onliner

```
perl -pi -e '@a=qw(a b c d e);$aa=join("\n",@a);s/string/$aa/g;' tt.txt
```